# Are my channel separation calculations correct?

Tags: java, opencv, hsv

I have an HSV image and I am interested in a certain area of the image. I have gotten image selection to work and determine the area I am interested in but I don't think the way I separate my channels is correct. My channel values don't come close to their actual value .The portion of the image I am looking at is white in RGB scale. I know that in HSV that white has a saturation of about (0..20) and a value(230..255) but the numbers printed out by the program don't come close in that range. I get a high 40 low 50 for S and -93 mostly for V. Are my channels calculations correct?

```
public void splitChannels() {

    Mat firstImage = Imgcodecs.imread("firstImage.jpg");
    int width = 20;
    int height = 20;
    Rect roi = new Rect(120, 160, width, height);
    Mat smallImg = new Mat(firstImage, roi);
    int channels = smallImg.channels();
    System.out.println("small pixels:" + smallImg.total());
    System.out.println("channels:" + smallImg.channels());
    int totalBytes = (int)(smallImg.total() * smallImg.channels());
    byte buff[] = new byte[totalBytes];
    smallImg.get(0, 0, buff);

    for (int i=0; i< height; i++) {
        // stride is the number of bytes in a row of smallImg
        int stride = channels * width;
        for (int j=0; j<stride; j+=channels) {
        //I don't know if these channels calculations are correct.
            int h = buff[(i * stride) + j];
            int s = buff[(i * stride) + j + 1]; 
            int v = buff[(i * stride) + j + 2];

            // Do something with the hsv.
            System.out.println("s: "+ s + " v: " + v);

        } 
    }
}
```

Here is my image:

[image]

The region of interest is the upper left sticker in the center, they are all white though.

The HSV it program prints out for this is:

```
h: 99 s: 78 v: 57
h: 97 s: 76 v: 55
h: 101 s: 77 v: 57
h: 101 s: 77 v: 57
h: 103 s: 79 v: 59
h: 103 s: 79 v: 59
h: 103 s: 79 v: 59
h: 102 s: 78 v: 58
h: 100 s: 76 v: 58
h: 99 s: 75 v: 57
h: 98 s: 74 v: 56
h: 98 s: 74 v: 56
h: 98 s: 74 v: 54
h: 99 s: 75 v: 55
```

Comment: Can you share the image?

Comment: updating my question I will add them @RossPresser

Comment: A good way to understand what is happening in your code is to create an image of constant (known) HSV values and try it on your algorithm.

Comment: Ok I just tried a white image and the values were around `h: 122 s: 63 v: 67` @DaveS

Comment: As far as I know that isn't close to the correct HSV values of a white image.  White should have a `Saturation(0..20) and Value(230..255)` around that range. @DaveS That is why I am wondering if my calculation is wrong to get those values.

Comment: @Cuber you state that you are able to select the area of interest. But are you able to confirm it?  That was the motivation of my suggest to try a test image of all the same pixel values.  You eliminate a number of variables, and it makes debugging easier.

Comment: I am able to confirm that it works for that specified area. I just noticed the problem though, it is my calculation for the channels the way I determine the integers is not correct and I don't know the right way to do it. I used a white image that is constant and I got all values as `h: -1 s: -1 v: -1
h: -1 s: -1 v: -1
h: -1 s: -1 v: -1
h: -1 s: -1 v: -1` @DaveS

Comment: @DaveS Ahhh that is equivalent to 255, 255 ,255 in unsigned format or RGB White!  The problem is the  Java byte data type is 8 bits long, however it is a signed data type, not unsigned.

Comment: So it is working but these aren't what the HSV values are meaning that I am representing something else right? @DaveS

Comment: @cuber you are getting the actual RGB intensities.

Comment: Oh interesting :) how do I get the HSV values though ?

Comment: @Cuber I just answered your question as a formal answer as stackoverflow doesn't like the length of this exchange in this format

Comment: Any reason why you're not using "cvtColor" and "split" opencv functions?

Comment: Not any particular reason actually but I did find out that I can do this with a lot less code using the `Core.split()`  @Miki

Comment: Exactly........

Comment: Don't worry I did implement that solution short after I figured out the problem and found that I could truncate it more @Miki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are getting the correct values but they are RGB intensities coming from the raw bytes. They are coming out -1 -1 -1 because  the Java byte data type is 8 bits long, however it is a signed data type, not unsigned.

You need to convert these values from RGB to HSV.  Try this:
Here is the link to the definition of the conversion:

[RGBtoHSB:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#RGBtoHSB(int,%20int,%20int,%20float[]))

Converts the components of a color, as specified by the default RGB model, to an equivalent set of values for hue, saturation, and brightness that are the three components of the HSB model.

```
public static float[] RGBtoHSB(int r,
                           int g,
                           int b,
                           float[] hsbvals)
```

Usage:

```
int r = ...
int g = ... 
int b = ...
float[] hsbvals = new float[3];
Color.RGBtoHSB(r,g,b,hsbvals)
```

Comment: That works but can I get separate HSV channels like I have the RGB ?

Comment: You have each component in the returned float array hsv, hsv[0], hsvt[1], hsv[2]

Comment: so white should be something this? `H: 0.0 S: -0.0 V -0.003921569
`

Comment: Oh ok when I google it though the HSV for white is 60 degrees for H and 0 for S and 100 for value.

Comment: I believe I am getting the correct values it is just that I have to understand how they are represented, I know this works but how is this `HSV(0°,0%,100%)` the same as this. `H: 0.0 S: -0.0 V: -0.003921569`

Comment: The reason I want to know is because I will be working with a wide range of colors later on and understanding how those float values represent the HSV on the right would become handy later.

Comment: I actually figured it out just now thank you a lot for the help :)

Comment: @cuber My pleasure :-)

Comment: One question though. If I have a image that is like "perfect" yellow and I have an image that is like "perfect" green the values are all 0.0. But when there is variation in the shade the values are reasonable. What do I do in that case if I happen to use one of these "perfect" colors? The program can't tell it apart.

Comment: @cuber - sure you can.  Remember, the raw data you have is RGB then you convert it to HSB.  You can differentiate based on the raw RGB values.